# Chained comparisons in MySQL get unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I had an issue with a MySQL statement that was returning null all the time, and although I was able to figure it out, the cause left me a bit puzzled.

This is a simplified version of the problematic query:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = id = 2;
```

The error happened because `id =` is repeated, removing one of the `id =` solved the problem (as there is a user with the id 2). But what has me a bit confused is how it "fails silently", returning 0 rows, instead of giving an error.

I tested a similar query on SQL Server, and got the error message `Incorrect syntax near '='` (something similar to what I would have expected from MySQL).

Originally, I thought that MySQL was making a **comparison between the first two fields** and the last one was the result of the comparison (with 0 for false, and 1 for true). Something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE (id = id) = 2;
```

But then I ran some queries that (kind of) contradicted that. Let me elaborate a bit more.

Imagine this table (called "users"):

```
id  | username
----|----------------
0   | anonymous
1   | root
2   | john
3   | doe
```

If I do `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = id = 1`, I get all 4 users. And with `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = id = 0`, I don't get any. That seems to confirm the comparison theory. But, things get confusing if I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = username = 1;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = username = 0;
```

None of the records have the same id as username (they are not even the same type: `int(11)` and `varchar(25)` respectively), but with the first one, I get one result back: "anonymous". And with the second one, I get all the users but "anonymous". Why does that happen? I see that it has something to do with the `id` being 0, because if I replace "anonymous'" id from 0 to 4, then I don't get it anymore with the first query (and it shows up in the second).

I guess it has to do with **MySQL turning strings/varchars into 0 when comparing with numbers**. But why does it permit chained comparisons in the same clause? What order does it follows when comparing them?

Things get *funny* when queries like this are valid, and actually return (*unexpected?*) values. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = id = id = username = username = id = username = 1;
```

returns the records with id 2 and 3, but no the ones with id 0 and 1. Why is that?

---

tl;dr version: Why do queries with chained comparison operation work? What is the order followed in the comparisons? Is this a bug or the expected behavior?

- A SQLFiddle with the database and the last query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f2ab/4

Comment: really interesting question. Looking at the `=` operator, it looks like it does do that kind of conversion http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal Also because `TRUE` and `FALSE` evaluate to 1 and 0 (respectively)

Comment: Personally I would expect the SQL Parser to complain that the SQL syntax is not valid.  I would think this is a bug but whether the MYSQL developers accept it as such is a totally different question

Comment: Very interesting...MySQL enjoys doing the wrong thing instead of throwing an error in a few circumstances, this appears to be another case.

Comment: This might help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f2ab/32

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Prerequisites to understand how chained comparisons in MySQL work

### Understanding SELECT-WHERE query

This is pretty obvious, but I'm making this answer for every programmer, even if you don't really know how SQL works. A `SELECT-WHERE` query, basically:

1. Loops every row affected by the query and
2. evaluates the `where_condition` with the values of that specific row.
3. If the `where_condition` results in `TRUE`, it will be listed.

A pseudo-code could be:

```
for every row:
    current values = row values # for example: username = 'anonymous'
    if (where_condition = TRUE)
        selected_rows.append(this row)
```

### Almost every string equals 0 (or FALSE)

Unless the string is a number (`'1'`, `'423'`, `'-42'`) or the string starts with a number, every other string equals `0` (or `FALSE`). The "numeric strings" equals its equivalent number and the "starting numeric string" equals its initial number. Providing some examples:
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 0;

```
+---------+
| 'a' = 0 |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

.

```
mysql> SELECT 'john' = 0;
+------------+
| 'john' = 0 |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

.

```
mysql> SELECT '123' = 123;
+-------------+
| '123' = 123 |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

.

```
mysql> SELECT '12a5' = 12;
+-------------+
| '12a5' = 12 |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

### WHERE_condition is resolved like Mathematical Operations

Chained comparisons are resolved one by one, with the only preference of parenthesis first, starting from the left until a `TRUE` or `FALSE` is what remains.

So, for example `1 = 1 = 0 = 0` will be traced as follows:

```
1 = 1 = 0 = 0
 [1]  = 0 = 0
     [0]  = 0
         [1]
Final result: 1 -> TRUE
```

## How it works

I will trace the last query, which I consider the most complicated and yet, the most beautiful to explain:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = id = id = username = username = id = username = 1;
```

First of all, I will show every `where_condition` with every row variables:

`id = id = id = username = username = id = username = 1`

```
0 = 0 = 0 = 'anonymous' = 'anonymous' = 0 = 'anonymous' = 1
1 = 1 = 1 = 'root'      = 'root'      = 1 = 'root'      = 1
2 = 2 = 2 = 'john'      = 'john'      = 2 = 'john'      = 1
3 = 3 = 3 = 'doe'       = 'doe'       = 3 = 'doe'       = 1
```

And now I will trace every row:

```
0 = 0 = 0 = 'anonymous' = 'anonymous' = 0 = 'anonymous' = 1
 [1]  = 0 = 'anonymous' = 'anonymous' = 0 = 'anonymous' = 1
     [0]  = 'anonymous' = 'anonymous' = 0 = 'anonymous' = 1
         [1]            = 'anonymous' = 0 = 'anonymous' = 1
                       [0]            = 0 = 'anonymous' = 1
                                     [1]  = 'anonymous' = 1
                                         [0]            = 1
                                                       [0] -> no match


1 = 1 = 1 = 'root'      = 'root'      = 1 = 'root'      = 1
 [1]  = 1 = 'root'      = 'root'      = 1 = 'root'      = 1
     [1]  = 'root'      = 'root'      = 1 = 'root'      = 1
         [0]            = 'root'      = 1 = 'root'      = 1
                       [1]            = 1 = 'root'      = 1
                                     [1]  = 'root'      = 1
                                         [0]            = 1
                                                       [0] -> no match


2 = 2 = 2 = 'john'      = 'john'      = 2 = 'john'      = 1
 [1]  = 2 = 'john'      = 'john'      = 2 = 'john'      = 1
     [0]  = 'john'      = 'john'      = 2 = 'john'      = 1
         [1]            = 'john'      = 2 = 'john'      = 1
                       [0]            = 2 = 'john'      = 1
                                     [0]  = 'john'      = 1
                                         [1]            = 1
                                                       [1] -> match


3 = 3 = 3 = 'doe'       = 'doe'       = 3 = 'doe'       = 1
 [1]  = 3 = 'doe'       = 'doe'       = 3 = 'doe'       = 1
     [0]  = 'doe'       = 'doe'       = 3 = 'doe'       = 1
         [1]            = 'doe'       = 3 = 'doe'       = 1
                       [0]            = 3 = 'doe'       = 1
                                     [0]  = 'doe'       = 1
                                         [1]            = 1
                                                       [1] -> match
```

The query shows the rows with `id = 2` and `id = 3` since they match the `where_condition`.

Comment: You might want to add why `0  = 'anonymous'` results in `1 (true)`

Comment: I did. in the part where I explain almost every string equals 0.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read it at first. But you are not entirely correct. If a string is  converted to integer, it may result in `0` but not almost always. Try these `'12a5'`, `'13b6'`, `'14c7'`

Comment: They will be converted to 12, 13 and 14 respectively. Now guess what `'16e3'` will be converted to.

Comment: Nice trick, but I'm guessing `'16e3'` equals `16E3` which is `16000`

Comment: Related question: **[MySQL is giving weird result](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56893/mysql-is-giving-weird-result)**

Answer (score 2):

I do not know MYSQL at all but suspect that you are encountering a side effect of the fact that each predicate on a where clause must evaluate to true.  E.g.

```
Select *
from table 
where 1 = 1
```

is in effect saying

```
Select *
from table 
where is_true(1 = 1)
```

I suggest you try other values than 1 and 0 and see what result you get.

Obviously (id=id) is true so in the use of 0 and 1 for false/true this is equal to 1

After some more experimenting Alvaro Montoro added to this that 
(int == int) = true; 
but for int > 1: (int == true) = false, and (int == false) = false.

Comment: This seems like a good lead. But does it work with the last query? It would be equivalent to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 = 1 = 1 = 0 = 0 = 1 = 0 = 1` and it should not return any record, but it returns 2... Or maybe I'm doing something wrong :-/

Comment: Forget that last comment. You are correct, because 2 and 3 are not considered `true` nor `false`

Comment: Try adding brackets.  I haven't actually desk-worked this but it would go something like 
(1=1) = 1= 0 ...
(1=1)=0...
(1=0)...

Comment: That's what I was getting a tough time with: `(((((((id = id) = id ) = username) = username) = id ) = username ) = 1)`. Now I see it better, I was getting confused with 2 and 3 not being considered `true` or `false` and assuming they would be `true`

Comment: The reason is that (int == int) = true; but for int > 1: (int == true) = false, and (int == false) = false. Please add it as a note on your answer, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = username = 1;
```

Would return true for "anonymous", 0 if it were parsed as:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = (username = 1);
```

`id` is 0, so it is saying "false = "false".

Note that these are *not* chained comparisons of any sort.  MySQL is turning the comparisons into integers (0 and 1) and then applying `=`.  So, `1 = 1 = 1` is true, but `0 = 0 = 0` is false.  So, this is a weird combination of binary logic and equality comparisons.

My advice is simply not to use more than one comparison in an expression.  Forget the fact that MySQL supports this -- it is not part of the standard and most databases do not behave this way.